# Multi checkbox search in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, checkbox

Now working on single checkbox search, I need multi checkbox search, my code is below:

```
<form class="fielter" method="get">
  <%= check_box_tag :title, "A" %> A
  <%= check_box_tag :title, "B" %> B
  <%= check_box_tag :title, "C" %> C
</form>
```

[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpaG5.png)

For example title`A, B, C & D` I need search all checkbox checked

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to name your form field `title[]`:

```
<%= check_box_tag 'title[]', "A" %> A
```

so `params[:title]` will be an array